# Is there a way I can deal with poeple using double quotes in csv files in pandas/python?

Tags: pandas, csv

I'm dealing with files we get sent by a client - so we can only get changes to the files we get sent with a lot of effort. Sometimes, in a free text field, we get a mention of length using the double quote characters to mean inches. For example, a file might look like this.

```
"count","desc","start_date","end_date"
"3","it is tall","3/18/2019","4/20/2020"
"10","height: 108" is nice,","04/11/2016","09/22/2015"
"8","it is short","7/20/2019","8/22/2020"
```

We are using python/pandas. When I load it using:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv", dtype=str)
```

I get:

[image]

There are two issues I am hoping to solve:

1. More important issue: I'd like the second value of `start_date` to be `04/11/2019` (without the comma at the start and the double quote at the end.
2. Less important issue: I'd like the second value of `desc` to be `height: 108" is nice,` (with the inches indicator).

I know that the right thing to do is to get the file escape the quote using `\"` but, like I said, that will be a hard change to get.

Answer (score 1):

You can exploit the pattern that the values are separated by `","` and remove first and last `"`. This solution will break if the free text field contains `","`.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

with open('sample.csv') as f:
    t = f.read()
print(t)
```

Out:

```
"count","desc","start_date","end_date"
"3","it is tall","3/18/2019","4/20/2020"
"10","height: 108" is nice,","04/11/2016","09/22/2015"
"8","it is short","7/20/2019","8/22/2020"
```

Remove first and last `"` in every row and `read_csv` with delimiter `","`

```
t = '\n'.join([i.strip('"') for i in t.split('\n')])

pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep='","', engine='python')
```

Out:

```
   count                   desc  start_date    end_date
0      3             it is tall   3/18/2019   4/20/2020
1     10  height: 108" is nice,  04/11/2016  09/22/2015
2      8            it is short   7/20/2019   8/22/2020
```